# getting my cell to start blinking based on the timer

Tags: java, timer

I have the following code which is basically colours the cell when the table contains certain criteria in this case an A in row 1 column 2:

```
package javaapplication63;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class NewClass extends JFrame
{
ColorRenderer colorRenderer;

public NewClass()
{
String[] columnNames = {"Date", "String", "Integer", "Boolean"};
Object[][] data =
{
{new Date(), "A", new Integer(1), new Boolean(true)},
{new Date(), "B", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
{new Date(), "C", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
{new Date(), "D", new Integer(4), new Boolean(false)}
};

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
JTable table = new JTable( model )
{
public Class getColumnClass(int column)
{
return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
}

// By overriding this method we can use a single renderer for every column

public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
{
Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
colorRenderer.setBackground(c, row, column);
return c;
}


};

table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300,400));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

// Create blinking color renderer

colorRenderer = new ColorRenderer( table );

colorRenderer.setRowColor(1, Color.GREEN);

colorRenderer.startBlinking(1000);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
NewClass frame = new NewClass();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

/*
** Color cell background
*/
class ColorRenderer 
{
private JTable table;
private AbstractTableModel model;
private Map colors;
private boolean isBlinking = true;
private Timer timer;
private Point location;

public ColorRenderer(JTable table)
{
this.table = table;
model = (AbstractTableModel)table.getModel();
colors = new HashMap();
location = new Point();
}

public void setBackground(Component c, int row, int column)
{
// Don't override the background color of a selected cell

//if ( table.isCellSelected(row, column) ) return;

// The default render does not reset the background color
// that was set for the previous cell, so reset it here

if (c instanceof DefaultTableCellRenderer)
{
c.setBackground( table.getBackground() );
}

// Don't highlight this time

if ( !isBlinking ) return;

// In case columns have been reordered, convert the column number

column = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

// Get cell color

Object key = getKey(row, column);
Object o = colors.get( key );

if (o != null)
{
c.setBackground( (Color)o );
return;
}

// Get row color

key = getKey(row, -1);
o = colors.get( key );

if (o != null)
{
c.setBackground( (Color)o );
return;
}

// Get column color

key = getKey(-1, column);
o = colors.get( key );

if (o != null)
{
c.setBackground( (Color)o );
return;
}

}

public void setCellColor(int row, int column, Color color)
{
Point key = new Point(row, column);
colors.put(key, color);
}



public void setRowColor(int row, Color color)
{
setCellColor(row, -1, color);
}

private Object getKey(int row, int column)
{
location.x = row;
location.y = column;
return location;
}

public void startBlinking(int interval)
{

if (model.getValueAt(0,1).equals("A")){//row 0 = first row/ column 2 = column 1
System.out.println("hello");
timer = new Timer(); //here is where i cant get the timer to start based on the interval
TimerTask tasknew = new TimerTask(interval) {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
};
timer.schedule(tasknew, 2000, 2000);
}
//timer = new Timer(interval,this);
//timer.start();
}

public void stopBlinking()
{
timer.stop();
}


}
}
```

However i cant appear to get the timer to start based on the interval specified which then should make the row blink can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two Timer classes

[javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) uses action listener and you start it by

```
timer = new Timer(4000, new ActionListener() {
    private int i;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        if (i%2 == 0)
            setRowColor(1, Color.RED);
        else 
            setRowColor(1, Color.GREEN);
        i++;
        table.revalidate();
        table.repaint();    
    }
});
timer.start();
```

and [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) that uses TimerTask and you start it by

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    private int i;          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        if (i%2 == 0)
            setRowColor(1, Color.RED);
        else 
            setRowColor(1, Color.GREEN);
        i++;
        table.revalidate();
        table.repaint();
    }
}, 0, 4000);
```

In your imports you are importing javax.swing.Timer but using it as java.util.Timer

Comment: That certainly helps, any ideas how to get the row to blink based on the Timer Task?

Comment: @MrAssistance You can use setRowColor defined earlier in your code

Comment: really grateful for your further assistance and creating the blinking cell. Many thanks